# YouTube iFrame does not count views

Tags: ios, iframe, video, youtube

I've embedded a video on my site using YouTube's new iFrame embed code, but sadly whenever I test-watch the video on my site, the view count doesn't get increased on YouTube. My video is not on autoplay and it doesn't have 300+ views (it has less than that) so that's not the problem.

I've also tried using the old embed code from YouTube and that works, the view counts increase everytime I test-watch the video from the site.

I'm asking this cause I can't use the old embed code since it's not supported by Apple. So my question is, is it normal that the iFrame code can't count views? What else can I do? Any help at all would be well-appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi having the same issue, please let me know i you find out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929539/youtube-iframe-does-not-trigger-counter-but-old-method-works

Comment: Hi, sadly I have not found anything that can help with this issue. Everyone just keeps saying to switch to back to the old embed code. But will keep you updated. Please do let me know too if you find out anything!

Comment: Tnx, my workaround is sending iframe only if user-agent is iOS. Lets keep in touch